# Text based jar file run in windows cmd error. How can this be fixed?

Tags: java

So I get this error when I try to run my very simple text based jar in Windows cmd:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader can not access
 a member of class me.Puffinlump.ItemDivider.Minecraftitemsdivider
 with modifiers "public static"
         at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:109)
         at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261)
         at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

It works fine in Eclipse but not with anything else. I don't know how to make a console for it that allows input and output or any console at all. Basically I can't make a console.

Here is my code:

```
package me.Puffinlump.ItemDivider;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Minecraftitemsdivider {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Values for the script
        String Itemname;
        String Thingname;
        int Iammount;
        int things;
        int Itemsperthings;

        //Question
        System.out.print("What is the name of your item? What type of things are you giving them to e.g. Player? How many are you giving? How many things are you dividing it among?");
        //The start of the input values.
        Itemname = keyboard.next();
        Thingname = keyboard.next();
        Iammount = keyboard.nextInt();
        things = keyboard.nextInt();
        //The end of the input values.

        //Math
        Itemsperthings = Iammount / things;

        //Printer
        System.out.print("Each ");
        System.out.print(Thingname);
        System.out.print(" gets ");
        System.out.print(Itemsperthings);
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(Itemname);
        System.out.print("s.");

        //Ending process
        keyboard.close();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class needs to be `public`, so change

```
class Minecraftitemsdivider
```

to

```
public class Minecraftitemsdivider
```